# How to sum all elements of a vector except the one we choose?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

My IDE is Code::Blocks 20.03 ( MinGW 9.2.0 )

My intention is to learn how to use `MASK` argument in intrinsic function `sum`.

This is my simple code:

```
program vector
  
implicit none 

integer :: i
integer, dimension(3) :: vec_aa, vec_bb

do i = 1, 3
  
  vec_aa(i) = i + 1  

end do

!do i = 1, 3
  
 ! vec_bb(i) = sum( vec_aa, mask = ?????? )  

! end do

end program vector
```

Is there a way to define `MASK` so that my function sums all the elements of the vector `vec_aa` except that element with index `i`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mask` needs to be a logical array of the same shape as `vec_aa`. It will function like an overlay over `vec_aa` such that only those elements `vec_aa(i)` will be evaluated where `mask(i)` evaluates as `.true.`.

For your problem you can easily accomplish that by creating an array using an implied do loop

```pascal
program vector
  implicit none

  integer               :: i, j
  integer, dimension(3) :: vec_aa, vec_bb

  do i = 1, 3
    vec_aa(i) = i + 1
  end do
  print *, 'aa', vec_aa      

  do i = 1, 3
    vec_bb(i) = sum(vec_aa, mask = [(j /= i, j = 1, 3)])
  end do
  print *, 'bb', vec_bb
end program
```

The output is

```
 aa           2           3           4
 bb           7           6           5
```

Comment: So, just co conclude: the `mask` is logical array which have `.false.` value at `i` position and the rest elements are `.true.` so the function `sum` will summarize only elements with that logical value?

Comment: @HarryKastorp I tried to append the answer according to your question. Does it help?